# Can't catch HttpRequestException

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, httpclient

I have following code

```
public async Task<T> SendData<T>()
{
    T result = default(T);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var p in ParametresToSend)
                    formData.Add(p.Value, p.Key);

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(URL, formData);

                string stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(stringContent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                ParametresToSend.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

It works perfectly, but if internet is not available after checks for it availability (very short time, but it possible), it catch **first** HttpRequestException. And after this, immediately will be throw **second** HttpRequestException, but catch block doesn't catch it and app geting crash. Why is it happining?

Comment: Well, in your `catch` you are re-throwing the exception (even if that;s what you wanted, you shouldn't, use plain `throw;`)

Comment: ... Or remove the `catch` block since it serves no purpose here (other than--to DavidG's point--destroying the stack trace as its currently written)

Comment: @DavidG, You right, but I have tried everything, and in all cases I still have second exception.

Comment: Yes, you have a second exception because you are throwing the exception again! What do you think `throw` does?

Comment: @Riko3412 are you observing these in the Output window in VS? Because that might give you the impression it is re-firing and not being handled (if you say it behaves the same without the catch). I have tried your code but cannot repro.

Comment: Now I see. I have just deleted catch block, and re-write my owner method for catching all exception inside it. Oh, I know about global exception handling, and I have tried it, but in Xamarin Forms it doens't work for me(

Comment: You should never ever delete your catch block from that code part where you think exception might occour.If you know the type of exception then handle it there else throw it from that part and handle it uppper layer or Global Handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-throwing the exception when you catch it, which is as good as not catching it in the first place.

Your app is crashing because there is nothing in place to handle this re-thrown exception - you do not have any global exception handling in place, which would be a very good idea if this is, itself, an ASP.NET app.

Answer (score -1):

```
      try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(URL, formData);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(stringContent);
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

try this

Comment: the poster wanted to catch exception but was nt able to figure out how two exceptions were getting thrown.

Comment: But this still rethrows the error, that's the problem!